# Sample color tool - QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, qgis-2, color

I try to use the sample color in the "Select color" in order to change the color of polygon layer in the map canvas. I sample the color from an image in Power Point - outside the QGIS system-2.12 version.

My problem is that the sign of the sample color tool [image]  changed into the regular arrow sign of the windows operation system:

[image]

How can I sample colors outside the QGIS software - using the sample color of the QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this before. In order to get it work try to minimize both windows of QGIS window and the the application window that is outside QGIS. Although, the sample color tool cursor will change to arrow or any other symbol, it can still work and get the target color. Just minimize both application windows to choose the color directly outside QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

When the dropper turns into an arrow outside QGIS, all you need to do is click the space bar and it should sample the colour you want outside QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I still can sample colors outside the QGIS software even sample color tool changed to the normal mouse cursor, between I'm using QGIS 2.14 version.